# Создание RichTextBox внутри TabControl

Tags: visual-studio, c#

Здравствуйте! Каким образом создать элемент RichTextBox внутри вкладок элемента TabControl, причем свойство Dock у RichTextBox было Fill?

Вкладки создаю таким образом:

```
foreach (FileInfo files in dirGadg.GetFiles())
{
     tabControl1.TabPages.Add(files.Name);
}
```

После в созданный RichTextBox будет загружено содержимое файла.

Спасибо.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

как-то так:

```
RichTextBox Box = new RichTextBox();
Box.Parent = TabControl1.TabPages[0];   //номер вкладки
Box.top = ...
box.letf = ...
box.width = ...
box.height = ...
box.show();
```

Comment: а если Box.Dock=DockStyle.fill ... будет работать?

Comment: Однозначно, будет. Просто допишите эту строку в конце кода.